# asp.net page location problem

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls

I'm creating usercontrol. This control use javascript 
 `<script src='js/my.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`

My web directory location is here>>

```
App_code\myusercontrol.css
User\aa.aspx
bb.aspx
```

`aa.aspx` And `bb.aspx` is use my created usercontrol. 
My problem is 
when i calling `aa.aspx`, successfully work
when i calling `bb.aspx`, javascript location error

I'm changing script to `<script src='../js/my.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`
when i calling `bb.aspx`, successfully work
when i calling `aa.aspx`, javascript location error

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify an absolute path to the script IE:

`<script src='/js/my.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`

Or you can resolve the URL dynamically through asp...

```
<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/my.js")%>' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. I love stackoverflow and greet programming experts.